# Which kind of diagram for parallel code documentation?

Tags: language-agnostic, diagram, mpi, boost-mpi

I have some parallel code (implemented using MPI) that needs to be documented. I'd like to have a flow-diagram describing it's high-level strategy.

What kind of diagram do you use to describe *send*, *receive*, *broadcast*, *gather*, *reduction* and other operations?

(EDIT: I'm equally interested in Linux/LaTeX software to do them)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's safe to say that there are no widely-used *de jure* or *de facto* standard diagrams and diagram types in use for what you want.  I tend, when I have to, to use MS Visio.  On Linux I'd look first at [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) and, perhaps, [PGF & TiKZ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/).

As for how to draw diagrams, I'd generally start with the nearest approximation I could find in one of the textbooks or papers knocking about my office.  *Introduction to Parallel Computing* by Grama *et al* has some nice diagrams.  You might learn by Googling around for terms such as 'algorithm animation' or 'visualization of algorithms'.

Comment: +1 for PGF & TiKZ, even if I was hoping for some specific package, like the one for automata and/or networks description.(and btw, everybody should know about TiKZ texamples (http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/)